# jQuery: cannot scale img with .load. It fills the entire page. I want to scale it down to fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am successfully loading the id #Meatball from file `NASA.html`. It is a very large img within `NASA.html`. I am unable to size down the image to 300x250px. I wanted the loaded element, whether its a video, image, or text, to fit within 300x250.

```
#contentframe{
position:absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 350px;
height: 300px;
}

#iframe{
  ?
}
<div id="contentframe">
    <div id="iframe"></div>
</div>  

$("#iframe").load("NASA.html #Meatball");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("#iframe").load("NASA.html #Meatball");
```

```css
#contentframe{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

#iframe * {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentframe">
    <div id="iframe"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfarbota/3mwc8xL7/

Comment: OH MY GOD. I LOVE YOU. I have been sitting here for HOURS. LEGEND!!!!! THANK you SO MUCH!

Comment: @MitPatel No problem, glad it helped! If this solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. You can also up-vote any answer(s) that helped you to give additional thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in css, set the height and width of that image to 300x250px.